# Global variables in python causing UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting the following error message whenever I run my code:

```
Attempting to parse Socialblade: https://socialblade.com/youtube/user/aantonop
Got no_of_videos: 325
Internal Server Error: /api/connect_youtube/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/test/projects/my-api/api/views.py", line 160, in post
    response.update(scraper.collect_creator_data(request.data['youtubeChannelUsername']))
  File "/Users/test/projects/my-api/api/scraper.py", line 23, in collect_creator_data
    process_socialblade(username)
  File "/Users/test/projects/my-api/api/scraper.py", line 68, in process_socialblade
    if no_of_subscribers:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'no_of_subscribers' referenced before assignment
```

I suspect its due to the use of global variables in my script but not sure how to rectify it. I have set up the global variables to be processed by multiple methods.

How do I fix it? Code below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from test.settings.base import YOUTUBE_URL, YOUTUBE_API_KEY

from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import ssl

no_of_videos = 0
no_of_subscribers = 0
no_of_views = 0
avg_views = 0
like_count = 0
dislike_count = 0
channel_id = None
photo = None
description = None
start_date = None
title = None
keywords = None
sb_grade = None


def collect_creator_data(username):
    process_socialblade(username)
    process_youtube(username)
    return {"id": channel_id,
            "photo": photo,
            "title": title,
            "like_count": like_count,
            "dislike_count": dislike_count,
            "keywords": keywords,
            "description": description,
            "start_date": start_date,
            "no_of_videos": no_of_videos,
            "no_of_subscribers": no_of_subscribers,
            "no_of_views": no_of_views,
            "avg_views": avg_views,
            "sb_grade": sb_grade
            }


def process_socialblade(username):
    socialblade_user_url = 'https://socialblade.com/youtube/user/' + username
    context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
    print('Attempting to parse Socialblade:', socialblade_user_url)
    q = Request(socialblade_user_url)
    q.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                               'Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11')
    q.add_header('Accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8')
    q.add_header('Accept-Charset', 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3')
    q.add_header('Accept-Encoding', 'none')
    q.add_header('Accept-Language', 'en-US,en;q=0.8')
    q.add_header('Connection', 'keep-alive')
    socialblade_user_html = urlopen(q, context=context).read()
    if socialblade_user_html:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(socialblade_user_html, "html.parser")
        youtube_user_top_info_list = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'YouTubeUserTopInfo'})
        for i in youtube_user_top_info_list:
            try:
                no_of_videos = i.find('span', id='youtube-stats-header-uploads').get_text()
            except AttributeError:
                pass
            if no_of_videos:
                print('Got no_of_videos:', no_of_videos)

            try:  
                no_of_subscribers = i.find('span', id='youtube-stats-header-subs').get_text()
            except AttributeError:
                pass
            if no_of_subscribers:
                print('Got no_of_subscribers:', no_of_subscribers)

            try:               
                no_of_views = i.find('span', id='youtube-stats-header-views').get_text()
            except AttributeError:
                pass
            if no_of_views:
                print('Got no_of_views:', no_of_views)
    else:
        print('Could not parse Socialblade:', socialblade_user_html)
```

Should I create global variables in `process_socialblade`?

Comment: When the function process_socialblade is called from another file, your definition of global variables in the beginning of scraper.py is not run. Not sure what is the best way to fix it though. You can put the definition in the function and export it as global for example or put the global variable in the outer file but it depends on your design then.

Comment: There must be a reason why you do it this way, but why use globals altogether? Also try/except with pass? You can use some data structure with defaults (dataclass, proper constructor with defaults, or a class).